# OpenBSD SMP support

Tags: openbsd, smp

The [OpenBSD 4.9 release announcement](http://distrowatch.com/?newsid=06655) says

> "SMP kernels can now boot on machines with up to 64 cores;"

So OpenBSD does support several CPU's/cores?

If i have a Core2Duo cpu in my laptop (t7100) then would it bring greater performance if I use "SMP" kernel?

If this is true, then how can I install/use an SMP kernel under OpenBSD 4.9?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SMP has been supported since OpenBSD 3.6, released in 2004.

Presumably the old limit was 4 cores or 16 cores.

The easiest way to get SMP support is to install the `bsd.mp` kernel.  That should happen by default if your system has multiple cores.

[OpenBSD SMP project](http://openbsd.org/smp.html)

> As of June, 2004, SMP (Symmetric MultiProcessor) support has been merged into the main OpenBSD development branch. At this time, the i386, amd64, mvme88k, sparc64, macppc and hppa platforms support SMP.

[OpenBSD/i386](http://www.openbsd.org/i386.html)

> Starting with OpenBSD 3.6, OpenBSD/i386 supports most SMP (Symmetrical MultiProcessor) systems. To support SMP operation, a separate SMP kernel (bsd.mp) is included with the installation file sets.

[What OpenBSD systems support SMP?](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq8.html#SMP)

> A separate SMP kernel, "bsd.mp", is provided with the install file sets. If multiple processors are detected at install time, is automatically installed as the default boot kernel, /bsd, and the single processor kernel is renamed /bsd.sp.

See also:

- [selecting the bsd.mp fileset](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq4.html#InstMedia).

Answer (score 3):

As an update to this question/answer, threading will become more useful in the 5.2 release, which will then supposedly make applications like mysql run faster.

If you are going to run the bsd.mp kernel for multiprocessor/multicore systems, even if it's NOT AMD, use the AMD64 platform instead of the i386 platform, as that seems to be the prevailing wisdom (from devs like Henning Brauer, re: bsdtalk interview with Peter Hansteen) on what runs 'better' on multicore systems right now.